# Connecting to RabbitMQ over SSL using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, rabbitmq

I try to use SSL for connect to RabbitMQ from .NET application.

RabbitMQ 3.8.8, Erlang 22.2, OS Windows

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
Inner Exception:
    IOException: No compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered []
```

**advanced.config**

```
[
    {ssl, [{versions, ["tlsv1.2", "tlsv1.1"]}]},
    {rabbit, [
        {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap]},
        {auth_mechanisms, ["PLAIN", "AMQPLAIN", "EXTERNAL"]},
        {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
        {ssl_options, [
            {cacertfile,"C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ SSL\\cacert.pem"},
            {certfile,"C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ SSL\\cert.pem"},
            {keyfile,"C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ SSL\\key.pem"},
            {verify,verify_peer},
            {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}
        ]}
    ]},
    {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
        {servers, ["corp.mydamain.com", "10.10.0.4", "10.10.0.6"]},
        {user_dn_pattern, "cn=${username},OU=IT,OU=USR,DC=corp,DC=mydamain,DC=com"},
        {dn_lookup_attribute, "userPrincipalName"},
        {dn_lookup_base, "DC=corp,DC=mydamain,DC=com"},
        {user_dn_pattern, "${username}@corp.mydamain.com"},
        {use_ssl, false},
        {port, 389},
        {log, true},
        {vhost_access_query, {in_group, "CN=GRP_ORG.IT,OU=ORG,OU=GRP,DC=corp,DC=mydamain,DC=com"}},
        {resource_access_query, {in_group, "CN=GRP_ORG.IT,OU=ORG,OU=GRP,DC=corp,DC=mydamain,DC=com"}},
        {tag_queries, [
            {administrator, {constant, false}},
            {management, {constant, true}}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

I try to remove *auth_mechanisms* parameter. Then I get error:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
Inner Exception:
    IOException: No compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered [AMQPLAIN PLAIN]
```

I use .NET RabbitMQ.Client 5.2.0

**Source code**

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "dtc01-betst1",
    Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.DefaultAmqpSslPort,
    VirtualHost = "/",
    AuthMechanisms = new AuthMechanismFactory[] { new ExternalMechanismFactory() }
};
factory.Ssl.ServerName = "dtc01-betst1.corp.mydamain.com";
factory.Ssl.CertPath = "cert.pem"; // the same file as in {certfile,"C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ SSL\\cert.pem"} in advanced.config
factory.Ssl.CertPassphrase = "";
factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
factory.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;

using (var con = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = con.CreateModel())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use forward slashes in your configuration file.

Since you are trying to use X509 certificate authentication, you must be sure that the [`rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl) plugin is enabled:

```
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl
```

If that does not resolve your issue I strongly suggest asking for assistance on the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list.